# Entity Editor - How to dynamically generate a list of components?

Tags: actionscript-3, reflection, dynamic, entity, metadata

I'm making a game and I an in-game editor that is able to create entities on the fly (rather than hard coding them).  I'm using a component-aggregation model, so my entities are nothing but a list of components.

What would be the best way to obtain or generate a list of components?  I really don't want to have to manually add entries for all possible components in some giant registerAllComponents() method or something.

I was thinking maybe somehow with reflection via either the knowledge that all components inherit from the base Component class, or possibly via custom metatags but I haven't been able to find ways to get a list of all classes that derive from a class or all classes that have custom metatags.

What sort of options am I left with?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a project I did once, we used a ruby script to generate an AS file containing references to all classes in a certain package (ensuring that they were included in the compilation). It's really easy considering that flash only allows classes with the same name as the file it's in, so no parsing of actual code needed.

It would be trivial to also make that add an entry to a dictionary (or something similar), for a factory class to use later.

I believe it's possible to have a program execute before compilation (at least in flashdevelop), so it would not add any manual work.

Edit: I added a basic FlashDevelop project to demonstrate. It requires that you have ruby installed. 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/340238/share/AutoGen.zip

Comment: This looks like an automated version of Torious's idea, which is perfect.  Thanks!  I'll have to look into how to get FlashDevelop to run this before compilation.

Comment: You can find it under project properties -> build -> pre-build command line. It's set up in my sample project as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no proper way of getting all loaded classes or anything like that in the Flash API right now. So finding all sub-classes of `Component` is out, inspecting all classes for a specific meta tag is out as well.

*A while ago I did run into a class/function that inspected the SWF's own bytecode upon loading to retrieve all contained classes. That's the only option for this kind of thing. See [this link](http://etcs.ru/pre/getDefinitionNamesSource/) and the bottom of my post.*

So, you're left with having to specify a list of component classes to pick from.

*One overly complicated/unfeasible option that comes to mind is creating an external tool that searches your source folders, parses AS3 code and determines all sub-classes of `Component`, finally producing a list in some XML file. But that's not a task for the faint-hearted...*

You can probably think of a bunch of manual solutions yourself, but one approach is to keep an accessible `Array` or `Vector.<Class>` somewhere, for example:

```
public static const COMPONENT_LIST:Vector.<Class> = Vector.<Class>( [
    CollisionComponent,
    VisualComponent,
    StatsComponent,
    ...
    ...
] );
```

One advantage over keeping a list of `String` names, for example, would be that the component classes are guaranteed to be compiled into your SWF.

If the classes aren't explicitly referenced anywhere else in your code, they are not compiled. This might occur for a simple component which you only `update()` once per frame or so, and is only specified by a string in some XML file.

**To clarify:** You could use the code in the link above to get a list of the names of all loaded classes, then use `getDefinitionByName(className)` for each of them, followed by a call to `describeType(classObj)` to obtain an XML description of each type. Then, parsing that for the type's super-types, you could determine if it extends `Component`. *I personally would just hardcode a list instead; it feels too messy to me to inspect* all *loaded classes on startup, but it's up to you.*

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I went with Jonatan's answer just because it's an automated version of your suggestion.  Thanks though.